# Seeking a Centralized Interface Solution for Managing Multiple 3D Printers in a MakerLab

Tags: software, octoprint, repetier, bambu

I'm responsible for a MakerLab in an engineering school, equipped with a diverse set of 3D printers: 5x Prusa MK3s+, 2x Prusa MK4, 2x Bambulab X1 Carbon, and 1x Formlab. Students currently initiate prints via USB/SD card on a shared PC. We're aiming to streamline this process by implementing a simple, centralized interface to manage all printers, view print histories, and start jobs. An ideal solution would also enable students to check print statuses from their mobile devices.

So far, I've explored Repetier Server, Octoprint, Prusa Connect, and Prusa Link. However, challenges have arisen:

- Repetier Server seems to require specific firmware, posing compatibility issues with our Bambulabs;
- Octoprint suggests running separate instances for each printer, which complicates centralization;
- While the Prusa MK3s+ could integrate with a Raspberry Zero, this doesn't solve our need for a unified interface.

**Specific Requirements**:

- Centralized control for all listed printers
- Ability to view print history
- Facilitation of print job initiation
- Mobile accessibility for students to monitor prints

Given these constraints and goals, does anyone have experience with or can recommend a solution that fits this setup? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Photo of MakerLab#1]

[image: Photo of MakerLab#2]

[image: Photo of MakerLab#3]

Answer (score 0):

For a printer to be controlled from a distance, the printer needs an advanced controller board or a dedicated controller board and a small interfacing board. Most printers have just a simple controller board, not being able to perform other tasks than sending G-codes to the printer.

Ultimaker printers have an advanced controller with enough performance to do more than just send G-codes, it also hosts a printing server host. You can connect to the Ultimaker cloud to access the individual printers and manage and browse through (un) finished prints.

There seems to be a solution for other printers, an example for Lulbotz printers, stacked in a farm is managed by software found on [AutoFarm3D](https://www.3dque.com/autofarm3d). Note that you are required to run a Separate Raspberry Pi 4 board next to the simple controller board.

Whether this operates with the Prusa MK4 printers is unknown, supported are:

> Recommended 3D Printers
>
> - Bambu Lab X1/X1C
> - Bambu Lab P1P/P1S
> - Bambu Lab A1 Mini
> - Bambu Lab A1 (coming soon!)
> - Prusa MK3/S/+
> - Prusa MINI
> - Artillery Sidewinder X1/X2
> - Artillery Genius/Pro
> - Creality Ender 3 S1
> - Creality Ender 3/Pro/V2
> - Creality CR10/V2/V3